# Java Open Source Course Management System

Tags: java, open-source, sakai

I'm looking for an Open Source Project for delivering a course trainings and to manage courses, instructors. I need something similar to [Moodle](http://moodle.org) but in Java.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://www.jediproject.net/

Answer (score 5):

There is [Sakai](http://sakaiproject.org/portal). Reasonably documented, but also pretty complex.

Comment: Yeah, this one seems very complex. I would like to see something with EJB's

Answer (score 2):

Here is alist of open source LMS (Learning Management Systems) written in Java:

http://www.roseindia.net/opensource/learningmanagementsystems.php